# Output from json_encode

Tags: php, json

i will get a output -->json_encode from select statement, but doesn't work. My screen is blank, please help me.
I work with xammp for Mac.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";   
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=app", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
     }   
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Name,Adresse,Latitude,Longi from Location"); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //var_dump($row);
        // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
        // to hold the data
        $resultArray = array();
        $tempArray = array();

        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results

    echo json_encode($tempArray,true);


$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: Your screen is blank because `$tempArray` is empty/doesn't exists.

Comment: where is `$tempArray `?

Comment: sorry the was the wrong code, now is the right code. my mistake

Comment: $tempArray  is not defined or exist so you try to json_encode null.

Comment: Sorry now is the right code

Comment: vad_dump $tempArray and post the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet works fine for me.

You could try it with `print_r` or something similar or check whether your database contains special chars

Comment: I print with var_dump($row) and get a array with my data (2 entry)

Comment: Could u post the output here?

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { ["Name"]=> string(5) "Frank" ["Adresse"]=> string(9) "Pappelstr" ["Latitude"]=> string(5) "37.45" ["Longi"]=> string(9) "45423.324" } [1]=> array(4) { ["Name"]=> string(7) "Jessica" ["Adresse"]=> string(10) "Am Gr�nzug" ["Latitude"]=> string(6) "34.345" ["Longi"]=> string(6) "33.345" } }

Comment: and  -->.  Connected successfully

Comment: "Am Gr�nzug" is something like "Am Grünzug", right? If so, try to rename the "ü" to "ue" in your database, just for testing

Comment: Hey ohhhhh men it woks , awesome , nice thanks for help

Comment: No problem, dude ;) Had the same problem a month ago hehe